# How can I use my Xperia X10 mini pro as an external speaker?

Tags: audio, sony-xperia-x10-mini-pro

I have an Xperia X10 mini pro. How can I use it as an external speaker?

Comment: Please be more specific. Do you want to connect a device to your xperia and have the audio routed thru the loudspeaker?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I like to connect the external device, which is stored a music files, to the xperia and then play the music through xperia. an example, to connect the mp3 player with xperia, but i need to use my phone as speaker. May be the external device can be change, like system or any other player.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any way to make your phone a remote speaker alone but there are methods that would achieve basically the same result.  Without knowing your exact goal it's hard to give you a specific recommendation but here is one way to have audio stored on a seperate device play through you phones speaker/headphones:

Setting up a wireless media server will allow you to stream media from your computer to you phone.  So while it's not simply acting as a speaker, you are able to hear media that is stored on your computer on your phone.

There are numerous ways to do this like using **[DLNA](https://market.android.com/search?q=dlna&c=apps)** or any of the number of apps that **[serve media](https://market.android.com/search?q=media+server&c=apps)** over wifi or 3G.

Answer (score 1):

I just installed [AirBubble](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bubblesoft.android.airbubble) which is seen, in iTunes, as an external speaker. Works great.

Answer (score 0):

The headphone jack has 3 channels. 1 mono mic and 1 stereo outputs. While you could modify a headset cord to input the mono channel from another set of headphone cables this would not produce any level of quality sound. I have a Xperia X10 and the frequencies on the mic input are narrow.

Highly recommend you copy the music from the mp3 player to a computer and copy from the computer to your phone. Add a larger micro SD card if necessary.